# How to export local Visual Studio mdf database to format for Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I have been creating an application in visual studio using a local database in a `.mdf` (SQL Server) database file. Recently, I created an Azure account and want to export the local database (with its structure and data) so that I can use it from Azure to allow for online connections. Visual Studio doesn't seem to export the create scripts for the tables (including the table data). Really strange how there's no standard way of achieving this. Visual Studio should have a database exporting tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export the database as a BACPAC file, which includes both schema and data, and then import into Azure SQL Database. This can be done from the SSMS GUI, sqlpackage.exe CLI, or PowerShell. See [these steps to export a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export). The BACPAC can be similarly imported into your Azure SQL Database.

Another method is the [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595). [See this MDA walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database). That tool also checks for compatibility issues during the process. Remember that to connect to a local database managed by Microsoft SQL Server, the name of the local server will be akin to: "(localdb)\V13.0". You will have to change the "V13.0" part to match the SQL Server version you are running. V13.0 Corresponds to Microsoft SQL Server 2017.